# Custom Form Field Type in Module Settings not got rendered (J4)

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-field, form-fields-types, joomla-5.x, custom-form-field-type

For my Project i need to render a custom form field based on the ListField
I try to use the "new" conventions for J4 and later using namespacing etc.

this is the relevant part of my xml:

```
...
<namespace path="src">NXD\Module\FootballManagerPlayers</namespace>
...
<config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic"
                      addfieldpath="/modules/mod_nxdfm2_players/src/models/fields"
            >
                <field name="team_id"
                        type="TeamSelect"
                        label="MOD_NXDFM2_PLAYERS_TEAM_FILTER_LABEL"
                        description="MOD_NXDFM2_PLAYERS_FILTER_DESC"
                        default=""
                        show_select="true">
                </field>
            </fieldset>
...
```

I've tried to place the FieldClass PHP on different locations within my module wihtout success. Currently the "TeamSelectField.php" is stored under "modules/mod_nxdfm2_players/src/models/fields" (But I think thats not correct?)

My TeamSelectField.php:

```
...
namespace NXD\Module\FootballmanagerPlayers\Fields;

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
...
class TeamSelectField extends ListField
{
    protected $type = 'TeamSelect';
...
protected function getInput()
    {
...
}

protected function getOptions()
    {
...
}
...
```

I'm using Dispatcher.php aswell as the service provider interface...
github Link to module code: [Link](https://github.com/marcorensch/nxdfm2_players)

I've tried different location that's why there are currently multiple "TeamSelectField.php" files in different locations like root/fields, src/Fields, src/models/fields , ....

I've used custom form field types already a few times in Joomla 3 / 4 by using the "old fashioned way" without issues. I'm aware that the conventions are strict but i didn't find any ressource on how to use it "the new way". Any suggestions hints are much appreciated.

**Edit**
Also adding the addFieldPrefix does not change anything:

```
...
<fieldset name="basic"
                      addfieldpath="/modules/mod_nxdfm2_players/src/models/fields"
                      addfieldprefix="NXD\Module\FootballmanagerPlayers\Field">
...
```

Answer (score 2):

**File / Folder Structure**

```
src /
- Field /
-- [FieldName]Field.php
```

**Namespacing**

In the XML:

`<namespace path="src">[COMPANY]\Module\ModuleName</namespace>`

Then you need to add the fieldprefix to the field or fieldset:

`<fieldset name="basic" addfieldprefix="[COMPANY]\Module\[ModuleName]\Site\Field">`

In the [FieldName]Field.php:

```
namespace [COMPANY]\Module\[ModuleName]\Site\Field;
```

Then as usual make sure the `protected $type = 'FieldName';` is identical to the call in the XML:

```
...
<field name="team_id"
  type="FieldName"
  label="YOUR_LABEL"
...
```

In conclusion the ...\Site... part was my mistake - even if the field has to be used in the Backend-Form we need to use "Site" because its a Frontend Module...